# how to search for matching items in an object list?

Tags: c#, list, object, search

Hi i have a class like this..

```
  class man    
  {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string houseid { get; set; }
   }
```

and I have a list of man like this..

```
 List<man> ppl = new List<man>();
```

I want to search if there are more than one person with the same houseid. If there are more than one man with same house id and if the number of people having same house id does not exceed limit 5 I want that house ids and the number of occurrences of that house id? Simply if there are houses with less than 5 members I want that house ids and the number of men under that house id? How to do that?

Comment: @AsadAli

Well i know only how to search for a given element in a list like this 
for (int i = 0; i < ppl.Count; i++)
                {
                    man tempman = ppl[i] as man;
                    if (tempman.houseif == "001")
                    {
                        //Do sth                     }}
That's why I posted here..

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var houses = ppl.GroupBy(x => x.houseid)  // 1
             .Where(x => x.Count() < 5) // 2
             .Select(x => new { HouseID = x.Key, Population = x.Count() }); // 3
```

1. Group the peoples based on *houseid*
2. Get the groups that contains less than five items
3. Create anonymous type for each group that contains the id of the House and the population.

Comment: How to do with a for loop?

Comment: @KanshaG ppl is List<man> and above query will give you a op of whole list then why you need to iterate it

Comment: @DhavalPatel

I want to assign some other men who doesn't have a house, in to houses which don't have five members.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
var houses = ppl.GroupBy(x => x.houseid)
                .Where(g => g.Count() < 5)
                .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, Count = g.Count());
foreach (var house in houses)
{
    Console.WriteLine("House {0} has a population of {1}", house.Id, house.Count);
}
```

Comment: How do i access that houseid and population of the house if which are less than 5> It would be great if this can be done with a for loop.

Comment: @KanshaG loop over the results and each item will have an `Id` / `Count` property (Id = houseid, Count = population).