# Search for matching items in an object list and assign values

Tags: c#, list, object, search

Hi I posted my question incompletely [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782492/how-to-search-for-matching-items-in-an-object-list/23782561?noredirect=1#comment36576068_23782561). I'm re posting it completely here again. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

I have a class like this.

```
class man    
{
 public string name { get; set; }
 public string houseid { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a list here Like this.

```
List<man> ppl = new List<man>();
```

I want to search for houseid s which are having less than 5 members and I want to assign members who are  not having a houseid to houses which are having less than 5 members. I have defined houseid's of members who doesn't have houses as NA..

And I want to check if the list already doesn't have houses which are having less than 5 members. with an if condition.

Comment: You will need a very intricate combination of for-statements and if-statements, I think you will most likely be better off using a different approach to your architecture. I would recommend using an Abstract House class containing a list of the actual House objects. Each individual House object can keep a running total of occupants, each individual member, and its' respective ID.  With an architecture as I mentioned, applying loops to check for your conditions will be a piece of cake!

Answer (score 0):

what does

> I want to search for houseid s which are having less than 5 members

if you want to search the ppl list you can easily do it with linq ,

```
 var pplWithNoHouseId=   from man in ppl
    where man.houseid =="NA"
    select man;
```

Answer (score 0):

linq is your friend...

```
     var housesWithLessThanFiveMembers =
        from p in ppl
        where p.houseid != "NA"
        group p by p.houseid into household
        where household.Count() < 5
        select household;
```

will find all houses with less than five members,and

```
     var peopleWithNoHouseID = 
        from p in ppl
        where p.houseid == "NA"
        select p;
```

will find all people with the houseid of 'NA'

If you don't care that adding members to a house might cause it's member count to go over five, then the solution is simple:

```
     var firstHouse = housesWithLessThanFiveMembers.First();
     foreach (man m in peopleWithNoHouseID)
     {
        m.houseid = firstHouse.Key;
     }
```

but if you do care, then...

```
     foreach (var house in housesWithLessThanFiveMembers)
     {
        int memberCount = house.Count();

        while (memberCount < 5)
        {
           man m = peopleWithNoHouseID.FirstOrDefault();

           if (m == null)
              return;

           m.houseid = house.Key;
           memberCount += 1;
        }
     }
```

this second way however might leave people who still have no house, because all of the other houses have five members already.

Comment: How to assign people with no houses to houses which are having 5 members.?

Comment: is that your only requirement? or must a house never have more than 5 members?

Comment: No there are no houses having more than 5 members.